# assigning variables in a list based on its value in relation to the other values in the list

Tags: python, list, random, variable-assignment

This function takes, as an argument, a positive integer n and generates 3 random numbers between 200 and 625, the smallest random number will be called minValue, the middle random number will be called myTaret, and the largest random number will be called maxValue.

```
def usingFunctionsGreater(n):
#create random numbers
aList=[]
for i in range(3):
    aList.append(random.randrange(200,625,1))
    #assign minValue, myTarget, and maxValue
```

the comments should help explain the program that i want to write, but I have no clue how to assign the variables to the elements in the list that is generated.

Comment: What is the role of *n* here?

Comment: Can't you just sort `aList` by ascending order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following:

```
>>> min, target, max = sorted([random.randrange(100, 625, 1) for i in range(3)])
>>> min, target, max
(155, 181, 239)
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @J.Wade If this solves your problem, rather than (or in addition to) saying "thank you" you could mark this answer as the solution.  You get rep, he gets rep, everybody's a winner.